# Correlation coefficient in case where dependent variable cannot be larger than independent

Tags: regression, correlation

I am trying to fit a linear correlation to data. Normally, an obvious choice would be Pearson's R^2, but in this case that over-estimates the accuracy of the data because the dependent variable can only deviate from this in one direction - a perfect fit is when the two values are equal, but the dependent value cannot ever be larger than the independent.

What is the best correlation metric to use here?

Comment: It really depends on what you need to do with it. I wouldn't have thought correlation would be the right kind of tool at all.

Comment: @Glen_b maybe it isn't. My goal here is to see how far the data deviate from a linear trend between x and y, given $0 <= y <= x$.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts or information about the mechanisms behind, or the statistical nature of, those deviations?

Comment: @whuber This is a sort of Bernoulli-trial experiment. Each data point represents the proportion of times a device successfully reported results. Each time it reports a result, this result may or may not be useful. This is why $y <= x$ : $y$ is a measure of the number of times the machine's result $x$ was useful. If the machine always works, $y=x$. I want to measure how close it is to that.

Comment: That is all useful and important information; thank you. (Please consider including it in the question itself.) Obtaining a correlation coefficient, however, does not seem to be terribly relevant in your situation. For instance, if on average $y=0.1x$ or on average $y=0.9x$ you will still obtain comparable correlations (near $1$). It would seem more useful to characterize how $y$ varies with $x$ or at least estimate the typical ratio $y/x$. Do you also have data on how many times the device was used in each case? That is relevant because it tells us the variance of $x$.

Comment: @whuber yes, I know how many times. That is the `x` value. The `y` value is the number of times the device succeeded. Right now, I fit a linear regression to the scatterplot of these points to show that there is a linear trend between the two. However, I am concerned that the $R^2$ value for this is skewed by $y <= x$.

Comment: You seem to have described *three* variables originally: the number of times the device was employed, the number of times "it successfully reported a result" ($x$), and the number of times it was "useful" ($y$). It would be helpful to edit the question to clarify exactly how the data were obtained because that will help identify a suitable model for the variability. It is good you are concerned, because the usual linear regression models are inapplicable: they assume the expected deviation is zero and do not accommodate the $y\le x$ restriction. $R^2$ is practically meaningless in any event.